# How can I print numbers in two rows as per order, first four in Row1 and next four in Row2?

Tags: jsp, for-loop, stringbuilder

```
<body>
    <%
        int apps = 8;
        out.println("<div>");
        out.println("<table>");
        StringBuilder Row1 = new StringBuilder();
        Row1.append("<tr>");
        StringBuilder Row2 = new StringBuilder();
        Row2.append("<tr>");
        for (int i = 0; i < apps; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                Row1.append("<td>" + i + "</td>");
            }
            if (i % 2 == 1) {
                Row2.append("<td>" + i + "</td>");
            }
        }
        Row1.append("</tr>");
        Row2.append("</tr>");
        out.println(Row1.toString());
        out.println(Row2.toString());
        out.println("</table>");
        out.println("</div>");
    %>
</body>
```

This is my jsp page. Currently I'm getting output as in Row1: `0 2 4 6` and in Row2: `1 3 5 7`. But I need output as in Row1: `1 2 3 4` and in Row2: `5 6 7 8`. How can I do that?

Comment: you are just appending even number to row 1 and odd numbers to row 2.correct ur logic

Comment: Sorry,i didn't get you,could you correct the logic,i need the output as 0 1 2 3 in Row1 and 4 5 6 7 in Row2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed only your conditions in `if` clause

```
for (int i = 0; i < apps; i++) {
            if ( i<4) {
                Row1.append("<td>" + i + "</td>");
            }
            if (i>3 && i<8) {
                Row2.append("<td>" + i + "</td>");
            }
        }
```

**Output** :

```
 Row1 : 0123  
 Row2 : 4567
```

Working demo : http://ideone.com/PMiknB .dint tried any html part